# "Party Rock Anthem" expressions meaning?

Tags: lyrics

I'm trying to understand some expressions of [LMFAO' "Party Rock Anthem".](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/lmfao/partyrockanthem.html)
Firstly what does rock mean in the title? Next, what is the meaning of the highlighted (`{}`) expressions/words below in the context:

```
...

Looking for your girl? She on my {jock} (Huh)
Non-stop when we in the spot
{Booty moving weight like she on the block} (Woo!)
Where the drank? I gots to know
Tight jeans, tattoo, 'cause I'm rock-and-roll
Half-black, half-white: {domino}
Gainin' money, Oprah, dough


Yo! I'm runnin' through these {hoes} like {Drano}
I got that {devilish flow}, rock-and-roll, {no halo}
We party-rock!, yeah, {that's the crew that I'm reppin'}
{On the rise to the top, no Led in our Zeppelin} (Hey!)

...

{Every day I'm shufflin'} (Shake)
Shufflin', shufflin' (Shake)

...
```

Comment: Just to let you know, some of the expressions you have highlighted are NSFW.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's interpretation of lyrics/poetry

Comment: Plus some of these could be answered with a google search.

Answer (score 2):

"Rock" is a genre of music. "Party rock" is rock music appropriate for playing at a party.

"Jock" is slang for penis. This term was more common a very long time ago, and it's a bit surprising to hear it used in a recent song.

"Booty" means the buttocks.

A "domino" is a playing piece in a game that is usually colored black with white pips to indicate a number value.

"Hoes" is slang for prostitutes, and is also used as a disrespectful term for women in general.

"Drano" is a brand of chemical used for clearing clogs from drain pipes.

"Flow" refers to the rhythmic pattern of rap music lyrics.

A "halo" is a ring or aura of light appearing around or above the head of angelic beings in the Christian tradition. It contrasts with "devilish" earlier in the same line.

A "crew" is a group of people who work together.

"Reppin'" is short for *representing*.

"Shufflin'" most likely refers to dancing, but could have other interpretations.

Comment: Nice answer, can you also add "no halo" meaning?

Comment: "No halo" means "without a halo". You'll find "halo" in a dictionary.